# Extending Ember.ArrayProxy

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do I extend Ember.ArrayProxy? I have tried the following:

```
Ember.ArrayProxy.reopenClass({
  flatten: function(){
    var r = [];

    this.forEach(function(el) {
      r.push.apply(r, Ember.isArray(el)  ? el.flatten() : [el]);
    });

    return r;        
  }
});
```

But ended up writing the following solution:

```
// Source: https://gist.github.com/mehulkar/3232255
Array.prototype.flatten = Ember.ArrayProxy.prototype.flatten =function() {
  var r = [];

  this.forEach(function(el) {
    r.push.apply(r, Ember.isArray(el)  ? el.flatten() : [el]);
  });

  return r;
};
```

Is there something I'm missing in the former example? I'm trying to stick with Ember's methodology, so I would prefer not to use the later.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `flatten` on instances of `ArrayProxy` you'd want to use `reopen`, and not `reopenClass`.  `reopenClass` adds the method to the class itself, aka you could call `Em.ArrayProxy.flatten()`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OqUFObeg/1/edit

Comment: I tried using this on ArrayProxy but the problem is that when I use .mapBy, I get an Array and it doesn't contain the flatten method. I've tried reopening the Ember.NativeArray class, but that doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to add flatten to the array prototype

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm debating. In an Ember application, am I supposed to extend the Array prototype or work with the built-in Ember classes? I'm having trouble trying to see where it should go.

Comment: If you just plan on using it on ember types only it makes sense to just add it to ember types, but if you want it to work on plain ol' array's you'd want to extend the Array prototype

Comment: I would prefer to only have it on Ember types, but unfortunately the mapBy function in Ember returns a plain Array. From the documentation it seems like it should be returning an ArrayProxy.